# Reuse methods within one service in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am using angular.js with phonegap. To get users gps location I developed a simple service:

```
app.factory('geolocation', function ($rootScope, cordovaReady) {
    return {
        getCurrentPosition: cordovaReady(function (onSuccess, onError, options) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function () {
                var that = this,
                    args = arguments;

                if (onSuccess) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        onSuccess.apply(that, args);
                    });
                }
            }, function () {
                var that = this,
                    args = arguments;
                if (onError) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        onError.apply(that, args);
                    });
                }
            }, options);
        });
    }
});
```

I call this service like this

```
geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
   console.log(position);
});
```

Now I want to extend the service with another method called **getCurrentCity**. This method should use **getCurrentPosition** to determine the city. So the service would look like this:

```
app.factory('geolocation', function ($rootScope, cordovaReady) {
    return {
        getCurrentPosition: ....
        getCurrentCity: ...
    }
});
```

Is this possible? How should I implement getCurrentCity by using getCurrentPosition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm answering the wrong question here, but if you're just asking how to return multiple methods from a service, it's quite simple:

```
angular.module('app', []).factory('geolocation', function ($rootScope, cordovaReady) {
    var locationObj = {
        getCurrentPosition: cordovaReady(function (onSuccess, onError, options) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function () {
                var that = this,
                    args = arguments;

                if (onSuccess) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        onSuccess.apply(that, args);
                    });
                }
            }, function () {
                var that = this,
                    args = arguments;
                if (onError) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        onError.apply(that, args);
                    });
                }
            }, options);
        }),

        getCurrentCity: function() {
            this.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                //determine city
                var city = ...
                //how to apply city to scope?
            });
        }
    }

    return locationObj;
});
```

If you're asking a phonegap-specific question, please disregard!

Comment: No this is not phonegap specific. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: hm I get "getCurrentPosition is not defined" in getCurrentCity method

Comment: Try changing it to `this.getCurrentPosition()`

Comment: I edited your answer so that it works for me, in addition how do I apply the city variable to scope so that I can pass it to frontend?